# what is the difference between freq='M' and freq='D' in fbprophet?

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

in fbprophet library

**what is the difference between:**

**first:**

```
future = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=7,freq='M')
```

**Second:**

```
future = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=7,freq='D')
```

Comment: could be that "M" represents "month" and "D" represents "days" to get different report intervals. 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prophet/prophet.pdf (page 8) mentions different freq options (however not exactly the same)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, fbprophet's `make_future_dataframe()` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/216), is a wrapper on pd.date_range. It supports a wide range of freq options, from which D stands for day and M for month. You can check out all the possibilities [in pandas docs.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html)